# Adding package to setuptools package list (using absolute imports) for Travis and Appveyor

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

I am porting a library to python 3 and keeping it compatible with python 2.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
mypackage/
    lib/
    engines/
    __init__.py
    setup.py
    <other_dirs>/
```

I want the setup to recognize `mypackage` as a package when I call `python setup.py install` in the mypackage directory.

So I set `packages = ["mypackage"]`. My local build passes, but the builds on Travis and Appveyor fail with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mypackage import VERSION
ImportError: No module named mypackage
```

(The `VERSION` variable is defined in `__init__.py`)

I am using python2 with `from __future__ import absolute_import` to maintain Python 3 compatibility.

Any idea how I can make the travis and appveyor build systems recognize my package? 
I found a similar question where the answer was to add a symlink to TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR for Travis. Nothing on Appveyor.